# Jar library not visible inside project packages

Tags: java, jar, package, libraries

I'm using easyeclipse and i have configured my build path to use external jar files and I can use the classes contained in the jars from the default package, yet I'm unable to access the jar from other packages.

Here's how it looks like:

[image: Project explorer]

You can see the jars in "Referenced libraries".

If i create a source in the default package i can use those algs4.jar and stdlib.jar fine, but I can't do it from the sources inside "Classic_Sorts" package for example

Comment: Have you tried pressing `Ctrl+Shift+O`..?

Comment: Yeah i've tried that, and it imports nothing